# Is there a way to obtain a transfer function of a system modeled in Dymola?

Tags: function, transfer, dymola

I have a hydraulic brake system model in dymola, I need to convert it into a transfer function so as to design a controller, does dymola have a transfer function library available to do so?

If there's a way to perform linear analysis as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can find nice tools for that directly integrated in Dymola at Tools → Linear Analysis:

[image]

Linearize will produce a file called dslin.mat in your working directory. That's a Matlab file and holds the ABCD matrices of the state space model. I prefer to load this file in Matlab or Python and do the linear analysis (including transfer function) there.

You can find a Matlab Script in Dymola's installation directory that helps you to load  the dslin.mat in Matlab. It's \Dymola\traj\tloadlin.m

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Modelica_LinearSystems2 library? In Dymola you find it under Tools.